Unable to match substring from variable in ACL
I'm setting-up mTLS authorization but I'm stuck.
I'm trying to check if a variable (ssl_c_s_dn) contains the content of txn.ou (defined as http-request set-var(txn.ou) str(/OU=),concat(,txn.subdomain,/)).
I'v tried
acl app_auth2 ssl_c_s_dn -m sub txn.ou
acl app_auth3 ssl_c_s_dn -m sub var(txn.ou)
acl app_auth4 ssl_c_s_dn -m sub %[txn.ou]
acl app_auth5 ssl_c_s_dn -m sub %[var(txn.ou)]

But ACL are always negative.
I've outputed content of ssl_c_s_dn and txn.ou and they are as epxected (ie. txn.ou is a substring of ssl_c_s_dn).
I'm I missing something ?
EDIT: Further tests
acl app_auth2 str(code/OU=code/code) -m sub str(code)
acl app_auth3 str(code/OU=code/code) -m sub code # The only one that is true
acl app_auth4 str(code/OU=code/code) -m sub %[str(code)]
acl app_auth5 str(code/OU=code/code) -m sub %[code]
acl app_auth6 str(code/OU=code/code) -m sub %{+Q}[code]
acl app_auth7 str(code/OU=code/code) -m sub %{+Q}[str(code)]

It seems that no funtions are used at all in comparaison. Is that the case ?

var(ssl_c_s_dn) -i -m sub txn.ou  (-i to make it case insensitive ), and var() see: Read a variable. ?

Sadly seems not to work, for acl app_auth10 var(ssl_c_s_dn) -i -m sub txn.ou I got: error detected while parsing ACL 'app_auth10' : invalid args in fetch method 'var' : invalid variable name 'ssl_c_s_dn'. A variable name must be start by its scope. The scope can be 'proc', 'sess', 'txn', 'req', 'res' or 'check' in ACL expression 'var(ssl_c_s_dn)'.
Tried with req.ssl_c_s_dn and txn.ssl_c_s_dn but ACL is never true.
Also, acl app_auth11 ssl_c_s_dn -m sub /OU=appname/ work as expected...
